# Android - screen rotation changing layouts with google maps fragment inside

Tags: android, layout, dictionary, orientation

I am doing app with googla maps api v2 for android. I created a layout for landscape and portrait orientations. Orientation changing works fine, but if there are something on map (like marker or line) it doesnt appears after orientation changing. So, in manifest i added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`. This helps to retain lines, markers and atc. on map but do not change layout to landsape. I tried to add this line when creating map `mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);`, orientaton works, but lines/markers are dublicated after every orientation changing and for example - if button was pushed in portrait mode and i changed phone orientation to landscape - button backs to it default state. What should i do? I need that lines/markers will retain after orientation changing and the new layout should apear with pushed buttons if them were pushed in previous orientation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, after some research I did this - first I checked if device was rotated, and if rotated added new layout programatticaly.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.. in your manifext..

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

<activity
             android:name=".Your Activity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```